# Some Permissions and Plugins dont work in the Nether, Players cant drop stuff anywhere. Any thoughts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

The most important ones are /home and silkspawners in general. The plugins I'm using are Essentials, EssentialsAntiBuild, EssentialsProtect, GriefProtection, SilkSpawners, SilkSpawnersEcoAddon, Vault, WorldBorder, WorldEdit, KitEssentials, ModifyWorld, ServerLogSaver, MorePotions, MagicSpells, EssentialsSpawn, ChestShop, LWC, and ive now replaced GroupManager with PermissionsEX because GroupManager kept causing problems. Switching to PermissionsEX did not fix the fact that people do not drop stuff when they die. **Edited to include all Plugins Jan28**

Now I have added the permissions to break and place silkspawners to both the default group usung groupmanager, and to the original permissions file, just in case, and that seemed to be doing fine - until someone went to the nether and tried to break a blaze spawner. It wouldn't let him destroy it, however, it gave him the drops anyways. Basically, free blaze eggs. Somehow I need to get silk spawners to actually let it be destroyed when broken in the nether.

**Switching to PermissionsEX fixed the /home problems.**

And lastly, the players drops are no longer dropping when they die in any of the worlds, even though I was pretty sure I had it set to do so. This means that, when they die, they can no longer aquire the things they lost because they stopped existing upon death. Did I miss something somewhere, or is this a bug for something? I can't remember whan it started, but I suspected groupmanager and couldn't find anything. Is it possible that the 1.7.2 version in general is doing this, because we upgraded? 
*Note that server difficulty is set to normal.

Thanks in advance for taking a look and trying to help~

Answer (score 1):

You're using GroupManager, which uses individuals permissions for each world. This may be the problem, try to copy your original "world" (or whatever the world name is) permissions config, and rename it to your nether world name. (by default, if your world name is default, the nether would be default_nether)

Comment: It still won't fix people's drops not actually dropping though. I'll do that, but teh drops thing is across worlds, not just the one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because of permissions.

Comment: I figured that much, but how do I fix it? which permission is it? Also, your earlier suggestion does not work.

Comment: I have no idea what permission is it, depends on what plugins you're using. Can you tell EXACTLY what plugins are you running?

Comment: Alright, I've edited the post to show every single plugin we have installed. We have switched to PermissionsEX since GroupManager just would not let anything work. Now /home and such works, but the other two problems are still kicking